# Which event is fired when completeMethod is executed on inputTextArea in PrimeFaces?

Tags: events, primefaces, jsf-2

I need to use [InputTextarea PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml) component, which allow use autocomplete mechanism between text. All works great, except for ***p:statusAjax***, when I'm typing, my loading var animation blocks screen.

I resolve this for [AutoComplete PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) component by adding next lines between `p:autoComplete`:

```html
<p:ajax event="query" global="false"/>
```

But when I try put this line between p:inputTextArea JSF shows error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /notificaciones/edit.xhtml @162,50 <p:ajax> Event:query is not supported.
> at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)...

I've read [PrimeFaces User Guide](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf) but for inputTextArea component there is no Ajax Behavior Section.

So, how can I know which event is firing when autocomplete method executed on `p:inputTextArea`?

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry, it was wrong, reference is to primefaces web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, the documentation is up-to-date so most likely there is no ajax event. But to be sure, you can always check the javascript source and/or the java source of the component ([the source is open and freely accessible](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces)).

You can always try without an event name to see if ajax is supported at all since all (most?) components have a default event.

I'm in a good mood and A quick check for you in the [java source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/inputtextarea/InputTextareaRenderer.java) and the [forms.js javascript](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_1/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js) source of 6.1 (which contains the js for this component and which is split in its own [forms.inputtextarea.js](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.inputtextarea.js) in the 6.1.3 Elite and upcoming 6.2 release) does not show any ajax events being used, so I think you are out of luck on this and need to file an [enhancement request in github](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/)

Comment: I'm cheking forms.inputtextarea.js, does not show any ajax evento, I will try to redesign how it works my page and I'll check requests in GitHub. Thank you.